# How do I create large CSVs in seconds?

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to create 1000s of large CSVs rapidly. This function generates the CSVs:

```
function csvGenerator () {

  for ((i=1; i<=$NUMCSVS; i++)); do
    CSVNAME=$DIRNAME"-"$CSVPREFIX$i$CSVEXT
    HEADERARRAY=()

    if [[ ! -e $CSVNAME ]]; then #Only create csv file if it not exist
      touch $CSVNAME
      echo "file: "$CSVNAME "created at $(date)" >> ../status.txt
    fi

    for ((j=1; j<=$NUMCOLS; j++)); do

      if  (( j < $NUMCOLS )) ; then
        HEADERNAME=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$j", "
      elif (( j == $NUMCOLS )) ; then
        HEADERNAME=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$j
      fi
      HEADERARRAY+=$HEADERNAME

    done

    echo $HEADERARRAY > $CSVNAME

    for ((k=1; k<=$NUMROWS; k++)); do
      ROWARRAY=()

      for ((l=1; l<=$NUMCOLS; l++)); do

        if (( l < $NUMCOLS )) ; then
          ROWVALUE=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-r"$k"c"$l", "
        elif (( l == $NUMCOLS )) ; then
          ROWVALUE=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-r"$k"c"$l
        fi
        ROWARRAY+=$ROWVALUE

      done

      echo $ROWARRAY >> $CSVNAME

    done

  done

}
```

The script takes ~3 mins to generate a CSV with 100k rows and 70 cols. What do I need to do to generate these CSVs at the rate of 1 CSV/~10 seconds?

Comment: If you want speed, don't use bash.  This is what "real" programming languages are for.  C, C++, Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript ... choose your poison :-)

Comment: Exactly what Stephen C said. This is the wrong tool for the job. Even awk would be a better choice. (Awk might actually be an excellent choice.)

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying that `bash` and "performant" don't usually go together in the same sentence. As other commentators suggested, `awk` may be a good choice that's adjacent in some senses.

I haven't yet had a chance to run your code, but it opens and closes the output file once per row — in this example, 100,000 times. Each time it must seek to the end of the file so that it can append the latest row.

Try pulling the actual generation (everything after `for ((j=1; j<=$NUMCOLS; j++)); do`) into a new function, like `generateCsvContents`. In that new function, don't reference `$CSVNAME`, and remove the redirections on the `echo` statements. Then, in the original function, call the new function and redirect its output to the filename. Roughly:

```
function csvGenerator () {
 for ((i=1; i<=NUMCSVS; i++)); do
    CSVNAME=$DIRNAME"-"$CSVPREFIX$i$CSVEXT

    if [[ ! -e $CSVNAME ]]; then #Only create csv file if it not exist
      echo "file: $CSVNAME created at $(date)" >> ../status.txt
    fi

    # This will create $CSVNAME if it doesn't yet exist
    generateCsvContents > "$CSVNAME"
  done
}

function generateCsvContents() {
  HEADERARRAY=()
  for ((j=1; j<=NUMCOLS; j++)); do
    if  (( j < NUMCOLS )) ; then
      HEADERNAME=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$j", "
    elif (( j == NUMCOLS )) ; then
      HEADERNAME=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$j
    fi
    HEADERARRAY+=$HEADERNAME
  done

  echo $HEADERARRAY

  for ((k=1; k<=NUMROWS; k++)); do
    ROWARRAY=()
    for ((l=1; l<=NUMCOLS; l++)); do
      if (( l < NUMCOLS )) ; then
        ROWVALUE=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-r"$k"c"$l", "
      elif (( l == NUMCOLS )) ; then
        ROWVALUE=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-r"$k"c"$l
      fi
      ROWARRAY+=$ROWVALUE
    done
    echo "$ROWARRAY"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"Not this way" is I think the answer.

There are a few problems here.

- You're not using your arrays as arrays. When you treat them like strings, you affect only the first element in the array, which is misleading.
- The way you're using `>>` causes the output file to be opened and closed once for every line. That's potentially wasteful.
- You're not quoting your variables. In fact, you're quoting the stuff that doesn't need quoting, and not quoting the stuff that does.
- Upper case variable names are not recommended, due to the risk of collision with system variables. [ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)
- Bash isn't good at this. Really.

A cleaned up version of your function might look like this:

```
csvGenerator2() {

  for (( i=1; i<=NUMCSVS; i++ )); do
    CSVNAME="$DIRNAME-$CSVPREFIX$i$CSVEXT"

    # Only create csv file if it not exist
    [[ -e "$CSVNAME" ]] && continue

    touch "$CSVNAME"
    date "+[%F %T] created: $CSVNAME" | tee -a status.txt >&2

    HEADER=""
    for (( j=1; j<=NUMCOLS; j++ )); do
      printf -v HEADER '%s, %s-csv-%s-header-%s' "$HEADER" "$DIRNAME" "$i" "$j"
    done

    echo "${HEADER#, }" > "$CSVNAME"

    for (( k=1; k<=NUMROWS; k++ )); do

      ROW=""
      for (( l=1; l<=NUMCOLS; l++ )); do
        printf -v ROW '%s, %s-csv-%s-r%sc%s' "$ROW" "$DIRNAME" "$i" "$k" "$l"
      done

      echo "${ROW#, }"

    done >> "$CSVNAME"

  done

}
```

(Note that I haven't switched the variables to lower case because I'm lazy, but it's still a good idea.)

And if you were to make something functionally equivalent in awk:

```
csvGenerator3() {
  awk -v NUMCSVS="$NUMCSVS" -v NUMCOLS="$NUMCOLS" -v NUMROWS="$NUMROWS" -v DIRNAME="$DIRNAME" -v CSVPREFIX="$CSVPREFIX" -v CSVEXT="$CSVEXT" '
    BEGIN {
      for ( i=1; i<=NUMCSVS; i++) {
        out=sprintf("%s-%s%s%s", DIRNAME, CSVPREFIX, i, CSVEXT)
        if (!system("test -e " CSVNAME)) continue
        system("date '\''+[%F %T] created: " out "'\'' | tee -a status.txt >&2")

        comma=""
        for ( j=1; j<=NUMCOLS; j++ ) {
          printf "%s%s-csv-%s-header-%s", comma, DIRNAME, i, j > out
          comma=", "
        }
        printf "\n" >> out

        for ( k=1; k<=NUMROWS; k++ ) {
          comma=""
          for ( l=1; l<=NUMCOLS; l++ ) {
            printf "%s%s-csv-%s-r%sc%s", comma, DIRNAME, i, k, l >> out
            comma=", "
          }
          printf "\n" >> out
        }
      }
    }
  '
}
```

Note that awk does not suffer from the same open/closer overhead mentioned earlier with bash; when a file is used for output or as a pipe, it gets opened once and is left open until it is closed.

Comparing the two really highlights the choice you need to make:

```
$ time bash -c '. file; NUMCSVS=1 NUMCOLS=10 NUMROWS=100000 DIRNAME=2 CSVPREFIX=x CSVEXT=.csv csvGenerator2'
[2019-03-29 23:57:26] created: 2-x1.csv

real    0m30.260s
user    0m28.012s
sys     0m1.395s
$ time bash -c '. file; NUMCSVS=1 NUMCOLS=10 NUMROWS=100000 DIRNAME=3 CSVPREFIX=x CSVEXT=.csv csvGenerator3'
[2019-03-29 23:58:23] created: 3-x1.csv

real    0m4.994s
user    0m3.297s
sys     0m1.639s
```

Note that even my optimized bash version is only a little faster than your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring your two inner for-loops to loops like this will save time:

```
for ((j=1; j<$NUMCOLS; ++j)); do
  HEADERARRAY+=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$j", "
done
HEADERARRAY+=$DIRNAME"-csv-"$i"-header-"$NUMCOLS
```